# How to call a WebApi from within of a controller Using the DependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-controller

I need to call a WebApi method from a controller:
I can call the webApi method, but I keep on to get the following exception message:
"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: request"
when I reach the last WebApi command inside the try block:

```
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

This is my code:

**FeeController from WebApi**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CalculateFee(FeeViewModel model)
    {
            try
            {
                Fee myFee = new Fee(model);

                CalculatedFee result = myFee.CalculateFee();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Exception occurred" + ex?.Message);
            }
    }
```

**WidgetController by standard Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Calculation(CalculationViewModel calculationModel)
    {
        var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<WebApi.FeeController>();

        var myModel = new ViewModel.FeeController.FeeViewModel()
        {
            id = 35,
            workHours = 5
        };

        var result = controller.CalculateFee(myModel);
        return Json(result);

    }
```

Comment: Actually it seems easier to call your service : `var result = new Fee(myModel).CalculateFee();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guillaume. I think you meant               `var result = new Fee().CalculateFee(myModel); `    I tested it, but I still get the same error

Comment: why do you even bother calling the constructor when you could just deal with the actual function?  Why the need to resolve the controller and why can't you jut call the "myFee.CalculateFee" directly?

Comment: I understand just now what you mean: don't use the webapi, but directly use the class used by the webapi.

Comment: yes, sorry was in a rush hence the typos :).

Comment: No problem! I don't know why I persisted to use the webapi at all costs. It works, thanks Andrei!